# Post remains featured in the bulletin even if [featured] tag is removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, locked-questions, community-bulletin, featured-tag

[This question](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site?cb=1) about nominations for Pro Tempore Moderators on [Computer Science Educators Meta](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/) was a featured question, but was [unfeatured on June 23](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/75/revisions).
However, it sometimes still appears as featured on the main page of [Computer Science Educators SE](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Screenshot of the featured question box, including freehand red circles]

This might have something to do with the fact that the post [was locked](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/75/revisions) shortly after the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag has been removed.

This bug also extends to the API. During a period when they question appears in the sidebar, the API route `/questions?tagged=featured&site=cseducators.meta` returns:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "discussion",
        "featured",
        "topic-challenges"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 2721,
        "user_id": 58,
        "user_type": "moderator",
        "accept_rate": 12,
        "profile_image": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ZnN3lJjklJg/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAWE/zqGtDAyXfjo/photo.jpg?sz=128",
        "display_name": "thesecretmaster",
        "link": "https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/users/58/thesecretmaster"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 91,
      "answer_count": 2,
      "score": 9,
      "last_activity_date": 1501024496,
      "creation_date": 1499711767,
      "last_edit_date": 1499961119,
      "question_id": 207,
      "link": "https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/topic-challenges",
      "title": "Topic Challenges"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "discussion",
        "faq",
        "featured",
        "new-users"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 3275,
        "user_id": 1293,
        "user_type": "registered",
        "profile_image": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxcsS.jpg?s=128&g=1",
        "display_name": "Buffy",
        "link": "https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1293/buffy"
      },
      "is_answered": false,
      "view_count": 127,
      "answer_count": 0,
      "community_owned_date": 1499432641,
      "score": 9,
      "last_activity_date": 1499616804,
      "creation_date": 1499431354,
      "last_edit_date": 1499616804,
      "question_id": 203,
      "link": "https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/what-does-a-new-member-need-to-know-on-this-site",
      "title": "What does a new member need to know on this site?"
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "discussion",
        "moderation"
      ],
      "owner": {
        "reputation": 266,
        "user_id": 23,
        "user_type": "moderator",
        "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/2cf2eee5993f6cf3b0b149c2f8c5a323?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG",
        "display_name": "Robert Cartaino",
        "link": "https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/users/23/robert-cartaino"
      },
      "is_answered": true,
      "view_count": 609,
      "answer_count": 7,
      "score": 15,
      "locked_date": 1498246037,
      "last_activity_date": 1498235396,
      "creation_date": 1496674251,
      "last_edit_date": 1498235396,
      "question_id": 75,
      "link": "https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site",
      "title": "Accepting Nominations -- Who should moderate this site?"
    }
  ],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": xxxx,
  "quota_remaining": xxxx
}
```

This includes the nomination post as well as the 2 featured posts (at the time of this edit).

---

As [Shadow the Hedgehog Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-the-hedgehog-wizard) mentioned in [their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297870/post-remains-featured-even-if-featured-tag-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment991731_297870), the same issue appears with [the Meta question containing the hat contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help?cb=1), which was locked shortly before the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was removed (see the [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/304500/revisions) for details) and is at the time of this edit still visible in the sidebar.

Comment: Caching will often leave a post in the Featured list for a few hours after the tag is removed, but a *week* is out of the ordinary and does sound like a bug.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's now been more than a week, and it disappears and reappears, and seems to effect every user.

Comment: This is using some unstable cache, SE developer has to manually kick/refresh it. (it happened more than once in the past.)

Comment: Still happening. Affects every user, and randomly shows up and disappears, at the same times for every user. It's always that meta post.

Comment: shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @SagarV no, we're talking here about whole week.

Comment: And it strikes again with the Silly Putty swag contest. :/

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard I think it's on purpose XD (I'm actually quite sure it isn't, but wouldn't it be funny?)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard Thank you for mentioning that. I've included it in the question.

Comment: @JNat some more insight then just Status-Deferred would be preferable.

Comment: I removed [tag:status-review] from a post that had been closed as a duplicate of this one back in April 8th, @Luuklag, and had meant to tag this one as [tag:status-deferred] then but forgot — this has been added to the bug duty rotation, and will be addressed as part of that duty rotation. Once someone picks it up, there'll be more updates here.

Comment: This is currently occurring for RPG.SE's community-ads post, which was unfeatured on July 24. Reported here: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11706/community-ads-for-2021-is-still-featured-on-meta

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is now fixed, hopefully permanently. The issue related to a bug in the [Tag Engine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296329/51) (which is used by the API and site when filtering by tags) that affected locked posts.

> bug in tag engine
> stopped refreshing indexes
> on locked posts; now fixed

Answer (score 5):

The contents of the community bulletin [are cached and only updated every 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342538/how-or-when-is-the-featured-tag-supposed-to-take-effect#comment1146889_342538), so it's not unusual to have to wait up to 24 hours for the daily script to update the bulletin's contents (remove un-featured posts, add new featured posts).

If you've waited 24 hours and the bulletin still hasn't refreshed, you should [ping an employee](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342538/how-or-when-is-the-featured-tag-supposed-to-take-effect#comment1146889_342538).

Comment: Providing this answer because other questions asking about this are being closed as duplicates of this otherwise unanswered question, which doesn't contain any sort of pointer to the 24-hour caching period.

Comment: I saw some changes ([these changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342538/139866)) take effect soon -- the community bulletin changed within a few after each edit (editing the tags of the two meta-posts). But the change was unreliable (as described). So there is some mechanism for a relatively fast change. Perhaps though, who knows, there's also some once-a-day process as well to ensure that caches on all server are coherent.

Comment: There is a way to force the cache of the community bulletin to refresh for mods: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353492/hot-meta-posts-allow-for-removal-by-moderators-and-thoughts-about-future-impro