# How or when is the featured tag supposed to take effect?

Tags: support, bug, community-bulletin, featured-tag

If I add or remove the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag from a meta-topic, that doesn't take effect immediately -- i.e. the text isn't immediately added or removed from the sidebar of the main site.

When and how does it take effect? E.g. is automated, how often does that task run, are there any known bugs, and how (or after how long a delay) can I tell if it's not working properly?

I did the following:

1. Add the featured tag to a topic

   The topic was later displayed in the side bar.
2. Add the featured tag to a second topic

   The second topic was later also displayed in the side bar.
3. Remove the featured tag from the first topic

   The *second* topic was removed from the side bar and only the *first* topic is now displayed there.

Is this a bug or will it fix itself I wait?

---

No, having seen it fixed three hours ago, I see the problem again now.

So perhaps I suppose it is a cache problem (and maybe varies depending on which server I happen to get).

Comment: The community bulletin is... cranky, to say the least. It's taking the data from  a data source that doesn't synchronize well with events.

Comment: Will it fix itself, do you know, or should I try to do something -- e.g. try to unfeature the 2nd topic, wait until the 1st topic is undisplayed, and then refeature the 2nd one?

Comment: Also I'm not sure you should close this as a duplicate when the previous topic has no answers.

Comment: It's allowed on meta sites (the software doesn't permit it on main sites). Also, an answer to that question would also address this one, due to the way caching works for the bulletin.

Comment: I'm not asking what's allowed -- I'm saying there's currently a problem with the featured tag (on a meta-site) and the sidebar (on a main site) having become desynchronised -- and should I try to fix (by experimentally editing the featured tag) again, or just wait?

Comment: In [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297870/post-remains-featured-in-the-bulletin-even-if-featured-tag-is-removed#comment967131_297870) someone wrote, "SE developer has to manually kick/refresh it" -- is that true, should I escalate this to SE?

Comment: OK it's fixed now, thank you. I don't know if somebody kicked it or whether it simply happened.

Comment: We generally recommend waiting a day and if it’s still wonky, ping a CM.

Comment: A note: I've provided an answer to the duplicate target question.