# Why did a question suddenly become featured when the last edit was almost a year ago?

Tags: bug, community-bulletin, featured-tag

I recently saw the following in the sidebar on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/):

[image: Screenshot showing featured question]

The third question listed there is a site-specific Meta question that I recognized from a while back. Curious as to why it would be featured now, I clicked into the question only to discover that it was featured and unfeatured almost a year ago:

[image: Screenshot of question timeline]

This shows that the last edit, and the one in which the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) was removed, occurred in October of 2019. Why, then, is this question showing as featured in August of 2020?

I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297870/post-remains-featured-in-the-bulletin-even-if-featured-tag-is-removed) from several years ago which may or not be the same underlying issue. That question has no answer, other than the possibility that it's a caching issue (hardly plausible when it's been ten months). Also notable is that in this case it seems like it only started showing as featured very recently (i.e. rather than being stuck as featured for the last ten months). I visit the site in question at least several times a day and I have not noticed it before today.

Comment: There was an issue a while back about re-featuring, when the automatic removal of the [tag:featured] tag was done silently and one of those posts was edited. However, as of 2015, that tag is now removed by an actual edit from the Community user, so that shouldn't be an issue here.

Comment: Brought this up on their site meta: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/why-is-this-old-historically-locked-question-without-the-featured-tag-showing-u

Comment: @Sonic - Why, out of curiosity? If it's already been reported here what's the benefit in cross-posting to the per-site meta?

Comment: @Mithical In case a moderator there did something behind the scenes, and isn't active here, they can respond.

Comment: Related: [Post remains featured in the bulletin even if \[featured\] tag is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297870/209901). While being a moderator in Spanish.SE I saw this happen some times: if a post was locked and had the "featured" tag, there were chances that removing the tag would keep it featured indefinitely. I had to unlock, retag again, wait for some hours and then retag.

Comment: Mi Yodeya moderator reporting in: No actions were taken on the post in question between October 2019 and when this Meta post was posted.

Comment: This looks like it directly relates to the same issue - for some reason, locked posts that were featured when locked, will randomly reappear in the Featured box. The question was locked before it was unfeatured.

Comment: @Catija That’s interesting because the question under discussion was part of series, all of which were locked and featured at some point, but this is the first time I’ve seen one of them get refeatured.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Can you confirm that my above comment is correct? Or did you normally only lock them after they were featured?

Comment: @Alex I don't recall for sure. If I had to guess, I'd say that I probably usually locked first to end voting, then edited to, inter alia, remove the `featured` flag. But I probably did those actions in the opposite order sometimes, too.

Comment: @Catija I don't think this is a duplicate. The question mentioned in that post was locked *after* it was unfeatured. This one, as you said, was locked *before* it was unfeatured. (Does the order not matter?)

Comment: @sonic I think the issue is about whether the post is in the Bulletin, not actually whether it has the tag or not, and if it's removed within a few minutes (as this was), it's the same whether it was before or after - regardless, I think saying that before vs after is a tiny difference and still likely the same exact bug.